# Next is not defined, but I don't understand how to define it in my function

Tags: node.js, sails.js

When I try to access /course/new I get an error `[ReferenceError: next is not defined]`.

How and where do I define next for my faulting function?
if I just add an argument `next`like I've done in earlier models I just get more errors.

courseController:

```
module.exports = {

  'new':function(req, res, err){
    Student.findOne(req.param('takes'), function foundStudent (err, student){
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!student) return next();
      res.view({
       student: student
      });
    });
  },

  create: function(req,res,next){
    Course.create(req.params.all(), function courseCreated (err, course){
      if(err) next(err);

      res.json(course)
    });
  }

};
```

Course model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    code:{
      type: "string"
    },

    name:{
      type:"string"
    },

    takes:{
      model: 'student',
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```

/course/new.ejs:

```
<form action="/course/create" method="post">
  <h2>Create a new course for <%= student.name %></h2>

  <input type="hidden" name="takes" value="<%= student.id%>"/>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Course Code" name="code"><br/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="student"><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Add course"/>

</form>
```

Student schema:

```
//A student can have take many courses
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name:{
      type: "string",
      required: true
    },
    username:{
      type:"string"
    },

    courses: {
      collection: 'course',
      via: 'takes'
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: @RajAdroit. I removed the if statements to chek for err and return next. But that didn't help. I just got other errors then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

```
'new':function(req, res, next){
    Student.findOne({id:req.param('student')}, function foundStudent (err, student){
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!student) return next();
      res.view({
       student: student
      });
    });
  },
```

The problem was with the param type also. By changing it to the `student` model that is actually wants to access instead of the collection `takes` it worked.

A special thanks to @AJS for the help.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is here:

```
 module.exports = {
     // you had err here instead of next as last argument
    'new':function(req, res, next){
     Student.findOne({_id:req.param('takes')}, function foundStudent (err,   student){
     if (err) return next(err);
     if (!student) return next();
     res.view({
       student: student
     });
   });
  },

 create: function(req,res,next){
    Course.create(req.params.all(), function courseCreated (err, course){
    if(err) next(err);

    res.json(course)
 });
}

};
```

Comment: If I remove `err` and add `next` instead I get another error saying `[Error: .findOne() requires a criteria. If you want the first record try .find().limit(1)]`

Comment: yes that means that you have made a mistake with your find query , related to mongo implementation

Comment: try this: findOne({tasks:req.param('takes')}

Comment: It still doesn't work I'm afraid. `ReferenceError: next is not defined`

Comment: did you add next as last argument for **new** controller?

Comment: `[Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] Details:  Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'student.tasks' in 'where clause'` is what I get now

Comment: i have changed task to takes , i didn't read correctly and you just copy pasted what i wrote lol

Comment: Haha that was a silly problem. But unfortunately it didn't fix it. Same message but replace `student.tasks` with `student.takes` :/

Comment: you haven't posted student schema

Comment: Updated with student schema

Comment: updated answer with this **{_id:req.param('takes')**

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to change the definition for the function `new` to:

```
 'new':function(req, res, next){
```

Comment: If I remove `err` and add `next` instead I get another error saying `[Error: .findOne() requires a criteria. If you want the first record try .find().limit(1)]`

Comment: that's probably happening because you don't have a value set  in req.param('takes'), so no single student can be found

Comment: You should validate params before using them and throw Bad Request Errors when required parameters are absent from your request.

Here is a link to the documentation that shows this solution is correct.
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/middleware

Answer (score 7):

for someone who made the same mistake as me,

I did

```
.get((req, res) => {
```

instead of

```
.get((req, res, next) => {
```

I forgot the next parameter

Answer (score 1):

You should pass next into the function

```
  'new':function(req, res, **next**){
    Student.findOne(req.param('takes'), function foundStudent (err, student){
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!student) return next();
      res.view({
       student: student
      });
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Sails documentation, the next() function is used to chain middleware together. So, your incoming request can be manipulated by middleware before reaching your controller.

I believe the correct way to implement your controller method would be:

```
'new':function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.param.hasOwnProperty('takes')) {
        res.status(400)
        res.view('400', {"message":"Parameter 'takes' is required but was missing in the request"});
    }
    Student.findOne(req.param('takes'), function foundStudent (err, student){
      if (err) { 
         res.status(400);
         res.view('400', {"message":"Sorry, there was a problem with your request"});
      if (!student){ ;
          res.status(404);
         res.view('404', {"message":"Sorry, there was no student found by that name or id"});
      }
      res.view({
       student: student
      });
    });
  },
```

This allows you to use proper HTTP codes in your API.